# GMSMapViewDelegate Method Don't Work

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm working with Google Maps SDK for iOS.
I want to see NSLog output when a marker is clicked. I used following delegate method of GMSMapViewDelegate:

- -mapView:didTapMarker:
- -mapView:didTapInfoWindowOfMarker: 
  But I didn't see any log that work.

Here is the my code. What do you think is missing?

```
#import "testViewController.h"

@interface testViewController ()

@end

@implementation testViewController{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView_.delegate = self;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:41.12
                                                            longitude:29.05
                                                                 zoom:12];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;


    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.12, 29.05);
    marker.title = @"burdayım";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    NSLog(@"ssssss");
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [_V_map release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting   `mapView_.delegate = self`; before `mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];` mapView_ will be nil when you set the delegate; set the delegate after the instanciation so your instance variable is not nil.